# cannot get rCarousel to work (nav width and autoscroll)

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

http://www.netwerkhoreca.nl/

I am doing something wrong, but i cannot find what....
Somehow i cannot get the rCarousel to work (top part which says "vrienden van het koksgilde").

I dont really know what i am doing wrong.
I followedthe instructions on this page: http://ryrych.github.com/rcarousel/

I double checked if my links to the scripts and css are right and they are. For some reason the nav of it wont work, neither will it autoscroll. Also i cannot set the width of the carousel to fit the box.

When i am looking with firebug i see that the elements get inline styles, that should have something to do with it i think?

Some help would be greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you only have 3 items in the carousel and they are all visible - therefore there is nothing to do when you click previous/next ;)

Line 33 in your css is the issue with it not fitting the box:

```
#topbox1 div, #topbox2 div, #topbox3 div {
    color: #888888;
    line-height: 17px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 14px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Its setting all div's width within each ID'd container to 100%, which is 300px, add to that the padding specified = 324px, which is why its breaking out. Same goes for your H1's just that they are not visibly broken however they are bleeding out of there containers.

Its cascading through the divs, the width you want with that padding maintained is 276px;

```
#topbox2 #carousel {width:276px;}
```

Will override the style and make it fit, however I would suggest you look at what's happening with the widths and make them a little more specific.

e.g

```
#topbox1 > div, #topbox2 > div, #topbox3 > div {
    color: #888888;
    line-height: 17px;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 14px;
    width: 276px;
}
```

So just the immediate child divs within the #topboxes and remove the width form the headings:

```
#topbox1 h1, #topbox2 h1, #topbox3 h1 {
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 24px;
   padding: 7px 10px 10px 14px;
}
```

Hope that makes sense!